# Retrieve all entries in listbox in for loop to code chart point for AddY in C#

Tags: c#, loops, charts

I am trying to use a for loop to iterate through my listBox1 on my motherForm to properly addY values for all entries in my listBox1 to my chart on the second form? The listBox1 entries are dynamic and the chart should respond accordingly if more entries are added.

The chart will correctly generate the columns on the x axis for the number of entries in the listBox1, but all columns have the same y axis value (only pulling the first entry instead of each one dynamically). The code is listed below.

```
private void Chart_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    for (int i = 1; i <= motherForm.listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
       this.chart1.Series["Minutes"].Points.AddY(Double.Parse(motherForm.listBox1.Items[0].ToString()));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You just have to use the `i` variable for the items.

```
for (int i = 0; i < motherForm.listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
    this.chart1.Series["Minutes"].Points.AddY(motherForm.listBox1.Items[i]);
```